# How to get a form to send after validating?

Tags: php, html, forms

After reading W3Schools chapert on validating I have set up my form and the validation by using the send self method, and the required fields and email validation work.

But I am now somewhat stuck as to how to get the validated data to send to the next step, which would be my original php file containing my email address..

I have tried using this but to no avail:

```
//if valid then redirect

if($valid){

header('Location: http://somewhere.co.uk/testvalidation2.php');

exit();

  }

}
```

If anybody can help me out I will be so appreciative as I am quite new to php.
thanks for reading.

Comment: You need to use some method - cookies or querystrings - for passing your data over.

Comment: hello thankyou for replying to me :)  basically I set up the form with just the html file which posted to the php and i got the results through to my inbox. Now my client has asked me to include the validation for correct/valid email address and a few required fields within the form so i am trying to get the validated form to send now to my original php which includes my email address so that it can be sent to my inbox..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're trying to do a self-submitting file, then you just need to understand that your page serves  more than one purpose.  It's a little confusing at first, but when you get it, it will make sense. Your page must be able to:

- Display initially
- Validate data
- Do something (send email) if data is good

Although you could send the data to another page on validation (as explained in another answer) you can also just implement something like the basic logic/pseudocode below in one page:

```
IF submit button not pressed //(first time in, just show page)
    $showform=true;  //to be used later to show the form or not
ELSE //must check data
    IF (DATA IS GOOD)
        //do your emailing
        $showform = false;  //All is good, don't show form - maybe just success message
    ELSE
        //create an error message
        $showform=true;  //need to show form again
    ENDIF
ENDIF

IF ($showform)
   //show the html form - sticky form is usually preferable.
```

Hopefully this makes some sense...

Comment: hmm so basically... I can add to the php, the send to email address if the validation is ok?

Comment: Yes, exactly - send the email if validation is good, display the form with a message if validation is bad, or just display the form as is the first time they see the page.  That's a self-submitting form.  I've done a video on this for a class I taught a while back - www.youtube.com/watch?v=ffCY-yi3W6U

Answer (score 1):

Don't redirect, you'll discard any POST data you have (and there isn't usually much point in validating input that isn't going to be stored, which is what POST is for).

Just put your form processing logic in the same page.

You can put it in a different file and `include()` it if you like.

Comment: Agreed, I just think they required a little more info regarding "form processing logic in the same page" ...